How can I quickly extract failed records details from the JSON returned by Bulk API?
I use Bulk API 2.0 to insert related records and I would like quickly to find a list of errors.
How can I achieve this if I receive JSON from bulk API with extra verbose information I don't need?

This can be used to quickly find out if there are any errors at all, 1 means there are some errors and 0 means none errors
cat result.json | jq '.status' 
And the following command can be used to receive text file (kind of CSV file without a header) with all errors
cat result.json | jq '.result.records.failedResults[].sf__Error' -r > result.csv
